# does breaking a word with a span tag effect seo

Tags: html, css, seo

I was wondering whether breaking up a word with a span tag to change the font size of the first letter, will effect google bots ability to read the word?  The words effected by this are keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why break up the word in the first place when you can just use a pseudo-element selector on a span around the word? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp

---

As John Conde reminded me, w3schools is not exactly a good website, so if you want a better reference http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-firstletter should work.

Comment: I am aware of the issues with that website, but I like the scratchpad feature for examples. I've now provided a link to another reference site as well, though.

Comment: ...Oh, huh, I just noticed the site I linked to has a scratchpad/sandbox feature as well. Guess I'll be properly relying on that from now on.

Comment: That's not an answer to the question.

Comment: Sometimes a direct answer isn't always the best way to assist the questioner. jppower175 wasn't asking the question out of casual interest, instead having an actual situation where the topic asked about could have been an actual issue; my response not only eliminates the need to worry about that, it also, in my opinion, makes the resultant markup and CSS more elegant than they would have been otherwise. I seem to remember there being some discussion on SO about such "answers" a few years ago, in fact; I'll link it if I come across it again.

Comment: I wanted to hear an explanation to the question because I was interested in it. John Conde answered it.

Answer (score 5):

No, this won't harm your SEO efforts. It's normal to use markup for visual effects and since `<span>` has no semantic meaning it clearly won't change the weight of the word to the search engines.

Comment: I think it will though, I've read that google treats it as a space so `<span>J</span>orge` becomes 'J orge' which is not what you want

Comment: @Rodolfo: Google also gives you results that contain spaces when you search for a word without them, so even if that's the case it all evens out.

Comment: @JohnConde read it in a response here http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31066/flipping-text-is-good-for-seo which means, could be true or not. It's just that, when in doubt, I tend to be conservative.  But it's ok anyway I think, you can always put the keyword normally somewhere else in the text, just in case

Answer (score 1):

There is no definitive answer: there are no specifications on what search engines do, and they are different. It is natural to expect that they ignore `span` markup, but they need not do that.

But if there is a simple way to avoid splitting a word with such markup, it is safest to take that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do both the compound and separate words. For example, the word paperweight can be optimized for both paperweight and "paper weight". Use the HTML span tag and Google will rank for both paperweight and “paper weight” and your user will see the proper paperweight. See https://plus.google.com/communities/104061601962995568302 for details and how this was proved.